# Generating random numbers until sum is 1000

Tags: java, arrays, loops, do-while

I am new to Java and programming overall. I am currently attending an introductory class to object oriented programming and need some help in writing a code. The program I am writing is for a dart game. I am supposed to randomly generate the number of times the dart hits a certain area of the board and store it into one array. Then in another array, I have to keep track of the scores. the scores should add up to a total of 1000 or over but I am having problem doing that. My program works fine but it does show the result even when the sum is under 1000. I even tried using do-while loop but i don't seem to get the right answer. Also I need help with shortening the lines 18-27. Here's my code, any kind of help is appreciated.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
public class Assignment3Q1
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Random darts = new Random();
    int [] timesHit = new int [10];
    int sum=0;
    int tosses=0;
    do
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < timesHit.length; i++)  
        {
            timesHit[i]= 20 + darts.nextInt(20);
        }
        int [] points = new int [10];
        points [0] = timesHit[0]*7;
        points [1] = timesHit[1]*5;
        points [2] = timesHit[2]*5;
        points [3] = timesHit[3]*5;
        points [4] = timesHit[4]*3;
        points [5] = timesHit[5]*3;
        points [6] = timesHit[6]*3;
        points [7] = timesHit[7];
        points [8] = timesHit[8];
        points [9] = timesHit[9];
        for (int i=0; i<timesHit.length; i++)
        {   
            tosses += timesHit[i];
        }
        for (int i=0; i<points.length; i++)
        {
            sum += points[i];
        }
        System.out.println(tosses);
        System.out.println(sum);
        break;
    }while (sum>=1000);
}
```

}

Comment: What are you doing in those lines?

Comment: *Fix this problem I've not really explained, and while you're at it, please rewrite the code in this section.too* isn't how this site works. Please [edit] your post to clearly explain the problem you're having with the code you posted, and ask a more specific question than *Can you fix it for me?*.

Comment: I have used a long method to multiply the elements of the array and would like to know if there is a way to shorten it like a for loop.

Comment: If after 10 hits the sum is less than 1000, what should happen?  Reset all values and try again?

Comment: Yes, it's not supposed to print until the sum is 1000 or more. That's what I can't figure out how to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct logic to keep looping until the desired result (sum >= 1000).   Also notice the use of the `multiplier` array so that the points can be calculated in the hit loop.  The other two sums can also be done in the same loop.

```
public class Assignment3Q1 {
   public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Random darts = new Random();
        int sum=0;
        int tosses=0;
        int multiplier[] = {7, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1};
        do
        {
            int [] timesHit = new int [10];
            int [] points = new int [10];
            tosses = 0;
            sum = 0;
            for ( int i = 0; i < timesHit.length; i++)  
            {
                timesHit[i]= 20 + darts.nextInt(20);
                points[i] = timesHit[i] * multiplier[i];
                tosses += timesHit[i];
                sum += points[i];
            }
        } while (sum<1000);
        System.out.println("Final Tosses="+tosses);
        System.out.println("Final Sum="+sum);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the multiplier array, that's a great way to solve my problem. But the program is still printing the sum even if it is under 1000. Ran your exact code and got this as the output-
282
908

Comment: I tested that case, and found it worked well for me (for example was printing the sum inside the while loop).  I found the looping would continue until the sum was finally 1000 or greater.  Can you please check again.  For clarity, I have changed the print statements.

Comment: Really sorry. I must've run the old program. Anyway, thank you so much!